# Grammatical name and function of the following body

Tags: grammar

'At the end of the forty days of mourning...' –  what is the grammatical name and function of this expression?

Comment: It's a preposition phrase headed by the preposition "at". Without context its function can't be determined for certain, but it is almost certain to be a temporal adjunct.

Answer (score 3):

This type of construction is called *[nested](http://www.grammar-once-and-for-all.com/syntax/prepositional-phrases-and-particle-verbs/)* or [*embedded*](https://books.google.de/books?id=FZK3AQAAQBAJ&pg=PA143&lpg=PA143&dq=%22nested%20prepositional%20phrases%22&source=bl&ots=NPeuxnn8-_&sig=MWMmy-q2oGpC6EnTUaO_tRpFFC4&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjY_dHJn6jaAhVIkRQKHRQrAQcQ6AEwB3oECAEQAQ) prepositional phrases. In your example, the first prepositional object *end* is modified by a prepositional phrase whose object is modified by yet another, i.e., one prepositional phrase inside another inside yet another, thus “nested”:

> { at *end* [ of *days* ( of *mourning* ) ] }

There is a limit to how long readers will hold their mental breath as they move through such nested constructions. Three seems a reasonable limit:

> The police found the revolver behind a clock on the south kitchen wall of his small apartment in Brooklyn.

Four nested prepositional phrases is over the limit for most readers, but three still sounds reasonable:

> The police found the revolver behind a clock on the south kitchen wall of his small Brooklyn apartment.

So a good rule of thumb is “one two, three, too many.”